# How I make a unique list without any duplication value using RxList in Dart or Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

How do I make a unique list without any duplication value using RxList in Dart or Flutter?

My expectation:

```
RxList<String> myList = ["Canada", "India", "Canada"];

print(myList); 
// My expectation: ["Canada", "India"];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
I found two best way to filter duplication.

First one:
RxList<String> myList = ["Canada", "India", "Canada"].obs;
print(myList.value.toSet().toList()); // ["Canada", "India"]

Second one:
if(!myList.contain(value)){
myList.add(value);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Set` to remove duplicates on your `RxList` which it's values a `List`:

```
RxList<String> myList = ["Canada", "India", "Canada"];

print(myList.value.toSet().toList()); // ["Canada","India"];
```